Continuous infinitive with modals
In the past I could/would/might/used to work for hours
Can we write "be working for hours" instead of "work for hours" to emphasize duration?

Once again, why do you ask? Have you encountered this usage somewhere? If so, where? What are your thoughts about its (in)acceptability and why? And once again, you give essentially no context.  Context is nearly always critical. Very few questions have answers that are independent of context.

Adam, I agree with @PaulTanenbaum. My impression is that you are sincerely trying to improve your English, but you are not listening to the advice of people who are here to help you. Please take some time to review recent comments.

.  "used to sit for hours" yes, but not "used to be sitting for hours".

But without "for hours" is OK:  What happened to the pickle barrel that used to be sitting next to the deli counter?     "used to be" means it no longer is, and so a temporal phrase expressing duration is not idiomatic.

Based on the title of your post, I think the answer to your question is Yes. When you use the continuous, it typically emphasizes duration. For example:

We were working for hours before we got any water.
We worked for hours before we got any water.

They mean the same thing, but the first sentence puts ore emphasis on the duration and makes it seem a little worse.
